# Code duplication in Elixir and Ecto

Tags: ecto, elixir

I want to compose a module out of smaller modules.

This is a module I have right now:

```
defmodule Api.Product do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  import Api.Repo
  import Ecto.Query

  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:name, :brand, :description, :image, :rating, :number_of_votes]}
  schema "products" do
    field :name, :string
    field :brand, :string
    field :description, :string
    field :image, :string
    field :rating, :integer
    field :number_of_votes, :integer
    field :not_vegan_count, :integer
  end

  def changeset(product, params \\ %{}) do
    product
    |> cast(params, [:name, :brand, :description, :image, :rating, :number_of_votes, :not_vegan_count])
    |> validate_required([:name, :description, :brand])
    |> unique_constraint(:brand, name: :unique_product)
  end

  def delete_all_from_products do
    from(Api.Product) |> delete_all
  end

  def insert_product(conn, product) do
    changeset = Api.Product.changeset(%Api.Product{}, product)
    errors = changeset.errors
    valid = changeset.valid?
    case insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, product} ->
        {:success, product}
      {:error, changeset} ->
        {:error, changeset}
    end
  end

  def get_product_by_name_and_brand(name, brand) do
    Api.Product |> Ecto.Query.where(name: ^name) |> Ecto.Query.where(brand: ^brand) |> all
  end

  def get_products do
    Api.Product |> all
  end
end
```

But I want to have different things other than `Product` which all have most of the same fields as `Product` except for `brand`. Therefore is it best to create a module which has all fields except `brand` and then all the modules containing those fields have that module as a field?

Here is my module that all modules would contain:

```
defmodule Api.VeganThing do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  import Api.Repo
  import Ecto.Query

  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:name, :description, :image, :rating, :number_of_votes]}
  schema "vegan_things" do
    field :name, :string
    field :description, :string
    field :image, :string
    field :rating, :integer
    field :number_of_votes, :integer
    field :not_vegan_count, :integer
  end
end
```

There will be no database table for `vegan_things`. But a few different modules which do have database tables will contain a `vegan_thing`.

Is this a good way to avoid the code duplication of rewriting every field in every module in Elixir?

Here is my current changeset:

```
defmodule Api.Repo.Migrations.CreateProducts do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:products) do
      add :name, :string
      add :brand, :string
      add :description, :string
      add :image, :string
      add :rating, :integer
      add :number_of_votes, :integer
      add :not_vegan_count, :integer
    end

    create unique_index(:products, [:name, :brand], name: :unique_product)
  end
end
```

So I'm basing the uniqueness on a field which would be in `vegan_thing` and a field which is only in `product`. Can I do something like this?

```
defmodule Api.Repo.Migrations.CreateProducts do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:products) do
      add :name, :string
      add :vegan_thing, :vegan_thing
    end

    create unique_index(:products, [:vegan_thing.name, :brand], name: :unique_product)
  end
end
```

Or do I have to put the `name` field directly in `product`? instead of `vegan_thing` to be able to use it as a unique constraint?

Comment: Like [`Ecto.Schema.embedded_schema/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#embedded_schema/1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros can be used for this situation:

```
  defmodule Vegan do
    defmacro vegan_schema name, fields do
      quote do
        schema unquote(name) do
          unquote(fields)
          field :name, :string
          field :description, :string
          field :image, :string
          field :rating, :integer
          field :number_of_votes, :integer
          field :not_vegan_count, :integer
        end
      end
    end

    def changeset(struct_or_changeset, params) do
      struct_or_changeset
      |> Ecto.Changeset.cast(params, [:name, :description, :rating])
      |> Ecto.Changeset.validate_required([:name, :description])
    end
  end

  defmodule Product do
    use Ecto.Schema
    require Vegan

    @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:name, :brand, :description, :image, :rating, :number_of_votes]}
    Vegan.vegan_schema "products" do
      field :brand, :string
    end

    def changeset(params) do
      %Product{}
      |> Vegan.changeset(params)
      |> Ecto.Changeset.cast(params, [:brand])
      |> Ecto.Changeset.validate_required([:brand])
    end
  end
```

For other functions dealing with `Ecto.Changeset`, then regular modules and functions should be fine for factoring out any duplicated code, as shown in the example above where `Product.changeset/1` calls `Vegan.changeset/2` to cast and validate the common fields.

Comment: Thanks. Do I put the base changeset in `Vegan` module, and a smaller version of it in the subsuming module?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer with a simple example.  In particular, `Ecto.Changeset.cast` will accept a schema struct or a `Changeset` as the first argument, allowing changeset functions to be composed.